# Why GetAccessRules() slows application so much? How to avoid it and get access rules?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, performance, profiler

"Profiler" says that this line slows down my application:

```
AuthorizationRuleCollection accessRules =  = fileInfo.GetAccessControl().GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
```

This line is executed for every file in a loop (recursive directory scan).

**How can I solve this performance problem?**

I need to get access rules for every file for current windows user. Is there any less expensive way to get them?

**UPDATE**

I'll try to explain one more time what I want to implement.

In each iteration of a loop I retrieve `FileInfo` from a `List<FileInfo>` object and write it's data to XML-file (such as: name, size, last access date etc.). Also I need to get **access rules** for this file for current windows user.

Is there any other way to get access rules than using `fileInfo.GetAccessControl().GetAccessRules()` ??

Comment: Which "Profiler"? If your program does not much else, it makes perfect sense that this line should take a large percent of time. That doesn't mean you can't find a way to speed it up, but even if you do, that line will take a large percent of the time, even though the total time may have decreased.

Comment: You probably have a choice of instrumentation, which includes I/O but does not give you line-level resolution, or sampling, which gives you line-level resolution but does not include I/O. In general you need both, but it sounds like your usage is so simple it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Captain ?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey can you speak in English? I can't even understand what you are trying to say

Comment: He's saying properly retrieving ACLs is inherently slow as quite some information has to be read from disk. If you can explain what you're actually trying to do, someone can suggest a more sensible and perhaps faster way, but it all depends on your requirements.

Comment: You put "Profiler" in quotes. What are you using to do your profiling?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Profiler is an utility in Visual Studio

Comment: OK, that's what I thought. Then my second comment applies.

Comment: @CodeCaster updated post, please take a look

Comment: Please show more than just the single line of code where you call it, show the entire loop if possible.

Comment: OK, thanks for the update. Since you are doing I/O (writing file info to XML file) then you probably want to use instrumentation rather than sampling, because that will tell you if getting ACLs is actually taking enough wall-clock time to be worth trying to speed up.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey it is really worth to speed up, believe me

Comment: Not if it's only 10% of wall-clock time. (You could be right. You could also be wrong. Never assume you know what's really taking time, unless you've proven it.) A simple way is to comment out that line and just write dummy data - see how much faster it is. If a lot, then you're right. Alternately, you could comment out the write, and see how long it takes.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain are you joking? What do you want to see? I just ask to propose another way to get access rules - thats all I'm asking for. If I don't show more code - then it does not matter

Comment: @MikeDunlavey I'm here not to discuss this. If you don't know the answer to my question - then you are free to leave this topic

Comment: Likely the problem is no single operation takes a long time, but you are doing a lot of them. By showing more code there may be workarounds that will let you lower the cost per iteration. Your attitude is making you fall in to a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377), odds are that line of code you are asking us about is not your real problem, but without more information we can't help you find it. There is no way to make that single line go faster, but there are other ways to do it than using that single line.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain can you give me your email or skype? The code is pretty large, and btw I'm not allowed to show it to public :/

Comment: I will not give you my Skype or email, I am not being paid to be your consultant (I feel it is kind of offensive to ask private contact info this site). Instead recreate the problem in a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post the code for that here.